# How to add two number and concatenate with one string in PHP?

Tags: php, concatenation, addition

I am trying to study PHP. Suppose i have two variable

```
$A=5;
$B=10;
```

then i want to print the sum as
Sum = 15

for that i wrote

```
echo "Sum=".$A+$B;
```

But i am getting only the value of $B. that means
my result is

```
10
```

What is the error in my printing statement?

Answer (score 1):

You need to check for the [operator precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) over here you statement'll be evaluated as

```
echo ("Sum=".$A)+$B;
```

instead you need to write it like as

```
echo "Sum=".($A+$B);
```

or you can write it like as

```
echo "Sum=",$A+$B;
```

[**Demo**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php)